# Async programing in Javascript - Promise.all() do not work as expected

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise, asynccallback

I'm stuck in *Async programming in Javascript*.
I know that [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) will run parallel.

Could you pls tell me what I'm wrong with this code below?

It should take `100ms`. But actually, it takes `200ms` :(

```js
// 1. Define function here
var getFruit = async (name) => {
  const fruits = {
    pineapple: ":pineapple:",
    peach: ":peach:",
    strawberry: ":strawberry:"
  };
  await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos'); // abount 100ms 
  return fruits[name];
};

var makeSmoothie = async () => {
  const a = getFruit('pineapple');
  const b = getFruit('strawberry');
  const smoothie = await Promise.all([a, b]);
  return smoothie;
  //return [a, b];
};
  
/// 2. Execute code here
var tick = Date.now();
var log = (v) => console.log(`${v} \n Elapsed: ${Date.now() - tick}`);
makeSmoothie().then(log);
```

Comment: api return list of photos and you are trying to get fruits.. how are they related?

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular no, await in `getFruit` is not blocking the parallel `getFruit` call that `Promise.all` is invoking.

Comment: @Nilesh Patel I just need some promise to measure along with detecting whether `Promise.all` is working correct or not. Especially, what I'm wrong with `getFruit()` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is fine, it is running as parallel as possible from client side.

You can test this by waiting on `setTimeout` instead of the fetch:

```
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 100));
```

It's possible the placeholder site is queuing connections on its side or something. Either way you should measure with something predictable, not network.

**Edit:**

Just to explain a bit more that won't fit in a comment.

Let's put my waiting trick into an actual function:

```
const wait = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
```

OK, now you would call this as `await wait(100)`. Now to compare:

- `await wait(100)`
- `await fetch(...)`

In terms of your code setup, they are the same. They are perform some async task that takes around 100ms and returns. If `Promise.all()` were not running this in parallel, the `wait(100)` version would certainly take 200ms or longer.

`fetch` is not as reliable of a test as `setTimeout` because it is running over the network. There's a lot of things you can't control with this call, like:

- Some browsers limit how many parallel connections are made to the same domain
- Lag in DNS or the server itself, typical network hiccups
- The domain itself might force 1 connection at a time from your IP

It's not clear exactly what is causing the apparent synchronous behavior here. Maybe you will find some answers in the network panel. But in terms of code, there is nothing else for you to do. It is provably parallelized with the `setTimeout` test, which is much more reliable as a test since it is just a local timer.

Comment: Hi bro, could you pls tell me why my fetch() does not run parallel? And what are the differences between `fetch()` and `await new Promise` of yours?

Comment: @Phong He already told you why **your** fetch does not run in parallel. Fetch can run in parallel but he is guessing that `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` is servicing the requests sequentially. Why `jsonplaceholder.typicode.com` does not respond in parallel may be due to a lot of things: all browsers have a connection limit to each IP address so you may be hitting that limit (remember, browser requests sometimes generate two requests - an OPTION request for CORS and then the real GET requests, that can be two connections), the website itself may have limited bandwidth etc.

Comment: One thing to try is request 100 images instead of 2. Some servers and routers will ramp up bandwidth allocation when responding with lots of data. Why are some network equipment and servers designed this way? So they can serve many clients equally instead of a single client fast

Comment: Thanks @slebetman & @Matt.
It's resolved. btw, What happens if I change `await fetch()` or `await wait(100)` by the code blocker like this `loop from 1 to 2000`. Does this becomes sync, right? As a result, `Promise.all()` do not work parallel?

Comment: @Phong correct, `Promise.all` can only _schedule_ async tasks in parallel. It can't convert a synchronous CPU loop into a separate thread or anything. `fetch` is naturally async which is why it can be scheduled by `Promise.all` at all